# What setting should I change to get the int value of an enum instead of its string representation when serializing?

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net, refit

What setting should I change to get the property value of an enum instead of its string representation when serializing an object?  I have the following class.

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    public int ContainerType { get; set; }

    public SolidForm SolidForm { get; set; }
}
```

(for example) NOW ---> my json  =

```
{ "ProductId" : 22222,
  "ContainerType" : 1111,
  "SolidForm" : "Solid"
}
```

but I need this after serialization. (not enum as string)

```
{ "ProductId" : 22222,
  "ContainerType" : 1111,
  "SolidForm" : 1
}
```

I want that all enums in my object converted to int.

this my settings of Json Serialization

```
JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
        Error = delegate (object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The default in Newtonsoft.Json is to serialize enums as int. Assuming you mean Newtonsoft.Json.

Is your enum decorated with the attribute `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`?